# CakePHP Successfully Sending Email Only to Certain Addresses

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am using CakeDC to create the Auth portion of my CakePHP app.
I set up the email correctly. The problem is that it is only sending correctly to Gmail. So when I try to register an @outlook.com email address - the email simply does not go through. Here is my EmailConfig class in the CakePHP Config:

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'cyborg@example.io',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('cyborg@example.io' => 'My Site'),
        'host' => 'example.io',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'correctusername',
        'password' => 'correctpassword',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    public $fast = array(
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        'sender' => null,
        'to' => null,
        'cc' => null,
        'bcc' => null,
        'replyTo' => null,
        'readReceipt' => null,
        'returnPath' => null,
        'messageId' => true,
        'subject' => null,
        'message' => null,
        'headers' => null,
        'viewRender' => null,
        'template' => false,
        'layout' => false,
        'viewVars' => null,
        'attachments' => null,
        'emailFormat' => null,
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => true,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

}
```

Checked junk and other folders - it's not there.

Comment: That's probably not a cake propblem, per-se, and more of a spam problem. you need to check your mail server's logs to see what happens after cake hands over the email and the server tries to actually deliver it to the places where the emails aren't arriving.

Comment: What are you using as your SMTP server?

Comment: @MarcB I'll check it out

Comment: @developerwjk - I'm using Dreamhost's webmail. They usually require that you create an email on the domain in order to send emails and form communication so I did it that way.

Comment: Maybe they are blocking you from sending to outlook.com or vice versa.

Comment: Hmmm @MarcB - I see this error in my mail logs: `Final-Recipient: rfc822; example@outlook.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;itamar@outlook.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx4.hotmail.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 OU-002 (COL0-MC1-F28) Unfortunately, messages from
    208.113.157.50 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider
    since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your
    provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.

--A22AAB4005F.1393878547/iad1-shared-relay1.dreamhost.com`

Comment: There you go. Your mail server's IP has been blacklisted.

Comment: @MarcB But wouldn't my mailserver be DreamHost? Meaning DreamHost's mailserver was blacklisted?

Comment: Yes. that's why I said "mail server".